# C# search results, show at specific position

Tags: c#, sql, printing, hyperlink

I have this problem, i search the DB and return results which i turn into links and print them but with the way i have chosen  "Response.Write();" i get the results printed at the upper left corner, which sucks cause it messes up my whole page... :(

Is there a way i can print at a specific location (under the search bar preferably) and keep the results as links ?

Thanks in advance!

```
  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable PassRecord = new DataTable();
        String str = "select First_Name,Email_Account,Surname,id from ID where (First_Name like '%'+ @search +'%' ) OR (Surname like '%'+ @search +'%') OR (Email_Account like '%'+ @search +'%')";
        SqlCommand Srch = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        Srch.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            con.Open();
            Srch.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = Srch;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            PID = (int)(Session["id"]);                      
            int SaveTheFirst = PID;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            { 
                PID2 = dr["id"].ToString() ;
                if (PID.ToString() != PID2 )
                {
                    counter++;               
                    var field = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageView.aspx?Email=" + dr["id"].ToString()) + "'>" + (dr["First_Name"] + "").ToString() + "</a>";
                    Response.Write(field);
                    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                    Response.Write("<br/>");
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            string display = " Not Valid Search Criteria!";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't render things to the response using response.write, add controls to your markup (.aspx) file and bind them to data in the code behind.

Comment: u mean link labels and stuff, yes ok but if the user has 3 results and the other search has 10 results?